# "Upvote" vs. "up vote" vs. "up-vote"

Tags: word-choice, hyphenation

Should I use "[upvote](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/upvote)", "up vote", or "up-vote" on SE sites? What about "[downvote](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/downvote)"? They're not words in the sense that they're in the dictionary, but they are commonly used in this community. Also, "downvote" reads much more naturally than "down vote".

> I upvoted the post with ponies and
>   unicorns.

Or:

> I up voted the post with ponies and
>   unicorns.

Or:

> I up-voted the post with ponies and
>   unicorns.

Comment: I voted the post with the ponies and unicorns up.

Comment: Up I voted the post with the ponies and unicorns. @mplungjan. Put the most important information first, willya? Sheesh. We don't want to end up like [the awful German language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Awful_German_Language)!

Comment: Well I upped my votes so now up yours ;)

Comment: @RegDwightѬſ道: I read that, and up I flagged it, for moderator intervention. ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Within the nomenclature of this site, **upvote** seems to be the accepted term.

Otherwise, you could go for *up-vote* or *vote up* but not *up vote*.

**Upvote** and the hyphenated *up-vote* work because they are compounds and create a new verb. Though the resulting word is not in a dictionary, it works because it follows logical/existing morphology patterns, whereby the prefix 'up-' modifies the verb 'vote'.

*Up vote* with spaces does not work however, because it confuses the syntax of the sentence.

Comment: Unless you're using UK english, or course; they're slower to combine words there, and would prefer up-vote or even "up vote" where it's not causing confusion. Americans tendto combinewords beforethe restoftheworld. (Joking.)

Comment: @Neil: If you like the American hyphen-combination, wait until you read German or Greek. (Joking.)  I do tend to look at "up-vote" as literally one word/concept, though I'm not sure if this is my American upbringing or my computer geekiness (i.e. computer-like syntax).

Comment: I look at it the same way, as a single concept. To paraphrase what [Carol Saller](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/CMS_FAQ/new/new_questions01.html) has said many times, "the clear usage is the correct one."

Comment: I am English and generally approach things with a staunchly BrEng opinion. I think since this word only really exists in this context and is new, it doesn't particularly belong to either Am or Br... The community dictates, I think. If I were responsible for coining the term though, it would have probably been up-vote...

Comment: Glad to know this. As German I have the problem that my spell checker for English doesn't like **upvote** but my feeling says it is OK. I asked http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/158/where-is-a-correct-stackexchange-site-to-ask-about-english-spell-checkers where it was closed as off topic.

Answer (score 3):

I would also add that "up vote" throws off my reading stride because saying "I up ..." is improper english and my brain has to make a quick mental note that someone is coining a usage.

"Upvote" might be unrecognizable to someone not familiar with forums such as this, while "Vote up" would be understandable.

"Up-vote" actually strikes me as a noun, not a verb. At least that's how I turn a phrase into an adjective or noun, such as "the man-in-the-middle attack", or "a man-on-the-street interview".

I would vote for "up-vote" to answer the original question: it sounds more natural to my geeky & American ears. If I analyze it closely, I would view it as a noun being used as a verb. (Sorry, I don't always know the proper technical words to describe such things.)

Answer (score 2):

I posted a question on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), "[Can we downvote “down-vote” and “up-vote” in the Help Center and the associated tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382889/1364007)" where I linked to [the accepted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/20465/109567) to  by [Karl](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/6858/karl), and did some additional research which found that dictionaries and Meta Stack Overflow itself favour "downvote" and "upvote" over "down-vote" and "up-vote" respectively.

As this question asks (emphasis mine)

> Should I use "[upvote](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/upvote)", "up vote", or "up-vote" **on SE sites**? What about "[downvote](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/downvote)"?

the findings in my question are relevant:

> - Searches for ["downvote"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22downvote%22+created%3A2019), ["upvote"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22upvote%22+created%3A2019), ["down-vote"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22down-vote%22+created%3A2019), and ["up-vote"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22up-vote%22+created%3A2019) filtered by the creation date on Meta Stack Overflow show the common usage is unhyphenated:
>
>   [image: Posts by year and year - unhyphenated wins]
>
>   [image: Stacked posts by term - unhyphenated wins]

Sadly I couldn't construct an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams) comparison for the terms - it seems that hyphenated words are [difficult to search for](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92154/121001).

The usages of "downvote" and "upvote" outnumbers the usages of "down-vote" and "upvote" by more than 4:1, so I would say that "downvote" and "upvote" (which are in some dictionaries, e.g. [1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/downvote), [2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/upvote), [3](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/downvote), [4](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/upvote)) are perfectly fine and in common usage — on Meta Stack Overflow, where the data for the graphs came from, at least — I have no reason to assume that the rest of Stack Exchange will be any different.

Answer (score 0):

In English, some verb phrases are separable, some are inseparable, and some are both, and in some cases separability changes the meaning of the verb.  Observe:

separable:

> He told me off.

not

> He told off me.

also not

> He off-told me.

Inseparable:

> She called for more scrutiny.

not

> She called more scrutiny for.

Both:

> Turn the music up.
>
> Turn up the music.

Meaning change:

> He got off the bus.
>
> He got the bus off.

Up-vote seems to be in the "both" camp, (though I prefer separable).

Answer (score 0):

At the present time, it seems appropriate to use the following abbreviations on SE sites:

- UV - for upvote
- DV - for downvote

I've already encountered with those forms in comments for my answers several times. And I was able to understand the meaning of those abbreviations from the context easily.